# Set view at right in landscape mode in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have a custom view at the bottom containing icons in the portrait mode. I want this view at the right side of the screen in landscape mode. I tried to set the properties at runtime but it's not working. I am sure either I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Below is my XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.HomeActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/title_mirror"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        </FrameLayout>



         <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_mirror"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mirror_not_selected" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_review"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_review_not_selected" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.33"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile_not_selected" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

In the above XML LinearLayout with id navigation_view is my custom view. I want this view at the right side of the screen when in landscape mode. I tried to set below properties in runtime but this is keeping my view at top instead of right.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = view_nav.getLayoutParams();

        params1.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params1.width = 100;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        view_nav.setLayoutParams(params);

        img_mirror.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
        img_review.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
        img_profile.startAnimation(toLandAnim);


        //  constraintSet.connect(view_nav.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.fragment_container, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
        //  constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
    } else {
        // In portrait

        img_mirror.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
        img_review.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
        img_profile.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
    }
}
```

I am not sure how do I set the property of LinearLayout at runtime whose parent is RelativeLayout.

Comment: why dont you create a landscape version?

Answer (score 0):

Create another xml file containing your landscape layout. This xml file should have the same name as the one in portrait and it should be located in `res/layout-land`  (if the portrait layout is in the `res/layout` folder). Android will use the right layout depending on the orientation of the device and you will have to handle only the animations based on the code samples you provided.

```
if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

    img_mirror.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
    img_review.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
    img_profile.startAnimation(toLandAnim);

} else {
    // In portrait

    img_mirror.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
    img_review.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
    img_profile.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
}
```

`

For more information: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes